# How to transform Strings from a txt file to different substrings in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, substring

So I have this method loadLevel in my class LevelLoader and I want to read the file and convert it into a tilemap. That's basically an 2d array of Tiles. A tile has 2 parameters: id and damage

The file looks like this:

```
00.05;00.05;00.04;02.03;
00.05;01.00;01.00;02.03;
00.05;01.00;01.00;02.04;
00.05;00.05;03.00;02.01;
```

The first number is the id and the second value is the damage. This level has 4 rows and 4 columns.

Currently, my method looks like this:

```
public TileMap loadLevel(String path){
    Tile[][] tiles = new Tile[12][12];
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line = null;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for(int j = 0; j < line.length() / 6; j++){
                int id = valueOf(line.substring(j*6, 2);
                int damage = valueOf(line.substring(j*6 + 3, 2);
                tiles[i][j].setTile(id, damage);
                //this is where the error comes from
            }
            i++;
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new TileMap(tiles);
}
```

I use 12 as max width and height.
When I try to run this, I get a NullPointerException in my for-loop. I've tried different methods to load this file, but I cannot find a one that works.

Can Anyone explain why this happens and possibly say what I should do?
Thanks for reading this.

Comment: You code would be much simpler and less error prone if you would convert the parsing of the row Strings to using `StringTokenizer`, where you tokenize the String on the `';'` character.

Comment: Since you have only 2 parameters per 'Tile', why is it a 4 column row?

Comment: You should perhaps consider splitting the string instead of doing those divisions by 6. You could first split it using ';' as a delimiter and then '.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialized your `Tile` array elements, only the array.

For that, you need to use the following idiom:

```
tiles[outer index][inner index] = new Tile(); // assuming default no-args constructor
```

Default value for `Object`s is `null`, upon which you invoke `setTile`, hence throwing `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3):

You have created your array, but not its elements.

```
Tile[][] tiles = new Tile[12][12];
```

creates an array of `Tile`, but each entry is `null`. You need to explicitly create them, something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; ++j) {
        tiles[i][j] = new Tile();
    }
}
```